# Existence of an integral that looks like the rth order moment

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a monotonic function such that the number of its
discontinuity points is finite. For $t \geq 0$ let $m_t = \int_0^1 x^t f(x)dx.$ Then which of the following statements is true?

(A) There exists a $t \geq 0$ for which $m_t$ is not defined.

(B) $m_t < \infty$ for all $t \geq 0.$

(C) $m_t$ is defined and is equal to $\infty$ for all $t \geq 0.$

(D) $m_t$ is defined for all $t \geq 0$ and there exists $t_1,t_2 \geq 0$ such that
$m_{t_1} = \infty$ and $m_{t_2} < \infty.$

I was thinking of $m_t$ like the $t^{th}$ order moment of a random variable $X$ but I'm not sure of the range and domain, and the question is about existence of the moments. Can someone help me proceed?

Comment: If a function is monotonic then it has a finite number of discontinuity points, you don't need to write "such that".

Comment: @SuspiciousFred Your function is not defined at $x=0$, so it's not a valid counterexample. Though I apologize, I should have added that $f$ must be defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$. In the question $[a,b]=[0,1]$.

Comment: @Zima, the function $e^{-\lfloor x^{-1} \rfloor}$ and taking value $0$ at $0$ has an infinite number of discontinuities and is nondecreasing.

Comment: @SuspiciousFred you are right, I meant countable not finite.

Comment: Obviously $|f| \leq \max(|f(0)|, |f(1)|) = \lambda,$ so $m_t \leq \lambda \int\limits_0^1 x^t$ and these quantities are...?

Comment: @SuspiciousFred, could you tell me what is the value of $\displaystyle\int_0^1\!\!e^{-\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor}\mathrm dx\;?$

Comment: @SuspiciousFred, it should be equal to $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-n}}{n(n+1)}\approx0.211866832516\,.$$
Could you get the exact result in a closed form ? Please, give me an answer.

Comment: @WilliamM. So we get $m_t \leq \frac{\lambda}{1+t} $ If $\lambda$ is $\infty$, say for something like $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{1-x}$ then (D) should be the answer?

Comment: Can $\lambda = \max(|f(0)|, |f(1)|)$ be equal to infinity?

Comment: @WilliamM. Yes, right? For the function I wrote above, the maximum is $|f(1)|$ which goes to infinity.

Comment: How do you define $f$ at $1$ so that it is a monotone function? You wrote $f$ to be defined on $[0, 1],$ rather than $(0,1);$ and furthermore, $f$ is monotone, whether increasing or decreasing, $f$ is bounded by $\lambda$ defined above, and this is a real number by definition of a function.